# Combining multiple for loops that iterate over matrix python

Tags: python

hello I want to combine multiple for loops into one loop to make my code less complex.
the loop iterates over the elements in a list of lists and add +1 for every correct value.

so let's say i have

```
ink = 0
mouse = 0
rat = 0
matrix = [
['', 'article1.txt', 'article2.txt', 'article3.txt'], ['ink', 2, 3, 0], ['mouse', 0, 2, 1], ['rat', 0, 0, 1]]
```

and

```
for line in matrix[1:2]: 
    for i in line[1:]:
            if i > 0:
                ink = ink + 1
for line in matrix[2:3]: 
    for i in line[1:]:
            if i > 0:
                mouse = mouse + 1
for line in matrix[3:4]: 
    for i in line[1:]:
            if i > 0:
                rat = rat + 1
```

I'd want this to become one loop or atleast some shorter code that automatically does this, even if there would be more rows and columns in the matrix.

Comment: `for row in matrix[1:]: for col in row[1:]:` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So assuming a correct value is a value greater than 1, i did this: Also to have infinite values, i organized the results in a dictionary:

```
matrix = [
    ["", "article1.txt", "article2.txt", "article3.txt"],
    ["ink", 2, 3, 0],
    ["mouse", 0, 2, 1],
    ["rat", 0, 0, 1]]
results = {product[0]: [1 for a in product[1:] if a > 0].count(1) for product in matrix[1:]}

print(results)
```

I hope this is what you expected. Let me know if you need any adjustments or explanations. This would be the result for your example:

```
{'ink': 2, 'mouse': 2, 'rat': 1}
```

Comment: Yes this works and I am able to understand! 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way to improve your code, would be:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for row in matrix[1:]:
        d[row[0]] = len(list(filter(lambda x: x>0, row[1:])))

                 
>>> d
                 
{'ink': 2, 'mouse': 2, 'rat': 1}
```

This also could be compacted into one liner dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {row[0]:len(list(filter(lambda x: x>0, row[1:]))) for row in matrix[1:]}
```

Comment: Great so upvoted, but also could have d as a dict comprehension i.e.: `d = {row[0]:len(list(filter(lambda x: x>0, row[1:]))) for row in matrix[1:]}`

Comment: @DarrylG, true, I just wanted to stick to OP code to show him how he can improve his, but I'll add your comment in the answer as well

Comment: @IronFist--understood.  Sort of an interesting code golf problem with even shorter solutions such as `d = {row[0]:sum(x>0 for x in row[1:]) for row in matrix[1:]}`